# How to translate the famous saying "路漫漫其修远兮，吾将上下而求索" in Li Sao?

Tags: translation

"路漫漫其修远兮，吾将上下而求索" is a verse in [Qu Yuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qu_Yuan)'s classic [Li Sao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li_Sao). My translation is:

> My journey is so hard and nearly endless, I will keep going forward until I get to the end in someday.

Comment: one web search result: https://www.zhihu.com/question/21035983

Comment: Thanks. @user6065

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the most original characters that you have access to when trying to translate  - this way, you don't get affected by later people's (mis)translations. I think the oldest line should be 路曼曼其脩遠兮，吾將上下而求索.

Comment: 哈哈，中华文化博大精深，怎么翻译都感觉没魂，没韵 -_-.........

Comment: ………………………………还行。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wiki link you provided had the following reference:

> Stephen Owen (1996). An Anthology of Chinese Literature: Beginnings to 1911 (New York: W.W. Norton): 162–75.

Page 169 of the book contains the following section:

[image: picture]

> I bade sun-driver Xi-he, to pause in her pace,
>   to stand off from Yan-zi and not to draw night.
>   On and on stretched my road, long it was and far,
>   I would go high and go low in this search that I made

Here 路曼曼其修远兮，吾将上下而求索 matches up with:

> On and on stretched my road, long it was and far,
>   I would go high and go low in this search that I made

That at least makes one published translation, that you can use. According to the *Translations into Western languages* on the Wikipedia page, this is, also, the most recent translation.

---

[Other translations include](http://bs.dayabook.com/poetry/chu-ci-songs-of-the-south/encountering-sorrow):

James Legge's:

> The way was long, and distant far was my goal; I would ascend and descend, pursuing my search.

David Hawkes':

> Long, long had been my road and far, far was the journey; I would go up and down to seek my heart's desire.

Yang Hsien-yi's:

> The way was long, and wrapped in gloom did seem, As I urged on to seek my vanished dream.

and Monica Eileen Mclellan Zikpi's

> The road long, long, such vast distance —— I will go above and below in pursuit

---

David Hawkes' translation is also cited in Pleco's PLC dictionary:

> 路漫漫其修远兮, 吾将上下而求索。(屈原《离骚》)
>   lù mànmàn qí xiū yuǎn xī, wú jiāng shàng-xià ér qiú suǒ.
>   Long, long had been my road and far, far was the journey; | I would go up and down to seek my heart’s desire.

Answer (score 1):

路漫漫其修远兮，吾将上下而求索 -- The path is narrow and too long to see the end. But I will seek for it in backs and forths.